# How to write a reference for website

Tags: bibliographies

I got a pdf file from Xilinx website such as below:
https://www.xilinx.com/publications/prod_mktg/7-Series-Product-Brief.pdf

How I am going to write it in Latex if I want to have it as my reference in my thesis?

Thank you.

Huda

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is it for the bibliography?

Comment: I suggest you employ the catch-all `@misc` entry type to create a bibliographic entry for this document. Be sure to set `url    = "https://www.xilinx.com/publications/prod_mktg/7-Series-Product-Brief.pdf",` as one of the fields, to make sensible choices for the `author`, `title`, and `year` fields, and to load the `xurl` package. The bibliography style you employ will determine how (and if) the contents of the `url` field are displayed in the formatted bibliography.